# Windows 10 static routes being persisted?

Tags: windows-10, routes

Some of our laptop users are displaying persistence routes when entering "route print".

These entries belong to home network or venues they have visited. They have not being configured manually, nor GPO nor Registry entries.

Is this an expected Windows 10 behavior?

Thanks so much
Gabriel

Comment: Those can come from DHCP Option 249.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Will look into DHCP options.

Comment: For me, hard to believe that those users have that option at home low-cost routers....even more hard to believe that via DHCP option you could populate PC persistence routing table....as manually we need to do privilege elevation to do that...;-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share more details on the issue? Are those persistent routes in the active session or not?

Let me share few hints to properly define the context of the issue.

By reading your description I am under the impression that your client is mixing few concepts up - static route vs persistent static route. A static route configuration is manually set and will be erased after you reboot the machine. A persistent route instead,  will keep the configuration in the registry even after the laptop rebooted. A persistent route is added, does not happen by a chance. To add it you have to add "–p" in the route command and to remove the same.

Thus, if your user wants to remove the route has to issue the following command:

route -p delete [xx].[xx].[xx].[xx]

Note that your end-user might be required to have elevated privilege to run the command, so Run as Admin option in Windows.

Consider also that  "active" routes are just a rendering of the routing table as it exists at the time. They  can include routes that were learned (via a routing protocol) and were made "persistent" routes, those that have been explicitly defined because you need them even after a reboot.

Showing a route within the persistent, is not an issue itself unless you are experiencing somethin unexpected. For instance:

- they are showed in the "active session" of the route print when they are not supposed to kick in.
- they are not active when they should. It could be the case after resume /wake up  from sleep / hibernation. That is a common issue caused sonme time by the TCP autotunig when dealing with old equipment like laptops or home routers.

If you want to check that setting, run the following command from Command Prompt in Windows

netsh interface tcp show global

In case you want to give it a try  and disable the autotunig, just issue the following command:

netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

Comment: Hi Hyena, thanks. we know what to expect from a static and from a persistence route. None of them have been configured at those Laptops. The new thing in here is at "route print", section of Active Persistence Routes, they have entries (not expected, not even one). For example, if the user enter route print while at the office, at the persistence routes appear one entry related to their house network ....if they visited last week another venue for a week, it appears as well.

Comment: Hey Gaby, there could be few reasons.  If you can reproduce the behavior, remove the unwanted routes with the command said before. Logging can be enabled by checking "Show Analytic and Debug Logs" in the Event Viewer "View" menu and then navigating to "Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> TCPIP -> Diagnostic" and then enabling that log.
You can also use tools intended for diagnosing problems, such as Windows Performance Recorder (WPR), "netsh trace", logman, the PowerShell EventTracingManagement or NetEventPacketCapture modules, etc. Post here the results.

Comment: Hi Hyena, will ask for this, thank you!